# X11 window-close button when using single thread serving multiple windows

Tags: c, x11

In a large application using X11 I recently switched from one thread per window to single thread serving all windows.

Now the problem is that clicking the window-close button causes all windows to disappear.

I know about the option to disable the window-manager's handling completely (XSetWMProtocols) but I don't want to do that because I would need to implement my own window-decoration, -resize...

I am setting callbacks with XSetErrorHandler and XSetIOErrorHandler,

Previously only the single window of a thead disappeared and I used above-mentioned callbacks to do a long-jump, properly cleaning resources, then ending the thread. The other windows/threads continued running.

However those callbacks are not even reached now:

I have a breakpoint in those callbacks and on _XIOError but at that point all windows have disappeared already.

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a62300 in _XIOError () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
#1  0x00007ffff7a5fa0d in _XEventsQueued () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
#2  0x00007ffff7a51211 in XPending () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
#3  0x00005555555dcf54 in xwin4gRunI (T=0x7ffff7b832e8, Xwin4g=0x7ffff7b831b0) at ../xwin4/xwin4.c:257
```

From _XEventsQueued's source:

```
while((response = poll_for_response(dpy)))
    handle_response(dpy, response, False);
if(xcb_connection_has_error(dpy->xcb->connection)) {
    _XIOError(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

I have libx11-dev and libx11-xcb-dev installed but I guess it is not being used:

```
(gdb) f 1
#1  0x00007ffff7a5fa0d in _XEventsQueued () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
(gdb) p response
No symbol "response" in current context.
```

So I took a look into poll_for_response: nothing that looked like window-unmap/destroy.

And into handle_response. It has:

```
case X_Error:
    handle_error(...)...
```

A breakpoint in handle_error is not reached. But that could be due to it failing to use the libx11-xcb-dev debug-build.

It is possible that I forgot to move something from the giant old part of code to the less-giant new part of the code. Is there some XSetWMProtocols needed to let the above-mentioned callbacks be called before the windows disappear?

Comment: Why don't you use some GUI toolkit like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two more hours of searching I found that indeed another XSetWMProtocols call was needed. For those who run into the same problem: use it with WM_DELETE_WINDOW.